# SQL Convert ISO 8601 Timestamp to Date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Normally I would use the DATE() function to convert a timestamp to just a date for stakeholder consumption. However, I'm encountering a new timestamp format that I've not worked with and I'm not sure how to convert this to a date...

**Timestamp**: 2022-01-07T07:14:59.336355000Z

My normal query would have been:

```
SELECT DATE(created) AS DATE
FROM history
ORDER BY created DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

**What I'm looking for**, is to convert this timestamp to a normal date format w/o additional time info... **YYYY-MM-DD**

Comment: Does this resource provide the answers?  ... https://hevodata.com/learn/bigquery-timestamp-to-date-functions/

Comment: This is not a timestamp, because timestamp has no any format: it is stored internally and *may be* formatted at the output by the client software. If you need a date part of this string, then use the answer below, if you need to convert it to `date` datatype, then add `date(...)` over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a sub-string of constant length `10`, one could even select with [`LEFT(value, length)`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#left):

```
 SELECT LEFT(created, 10) AS created_at
 FROM history
 ORDER BY created DESC
 LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: This worked great. Thank you!!